# Number theory equation(diophantine)!

Tags: number-theory

Find all $x$, $y$ integers s.t.

$ 8(x+y)(x^2+y^2)=15(x^2+y^2+xy+1) $

I am new to Diophantine equation, I have tried all kinds of algebraic manipulations but in vain, I have also tried to think of it as a kind of polynomial and given that it has (1, 2) and (2, 1) as a solution to somehow divide the polynomial and to get an easier polynomial to decode.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but I think one approach is to consider the equation modulo $m$, for a suitable $m$. For instance, taking $m = 3$ leads to $x \equiv -y \mod 3$. Maybe taking $m = 5, 8$ leads somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to assume anything about the signs of $x,y.$

Taking $u = x+y$ and $v = x-y,$  we get $u > 0$ (because $x^2 + xy + y^2 \geq 0$) and
$$ (16u - 45)u^2 + (16u-15)v^2 = 60.   $$
If $u \geq 4$ the left hand side is at least $(64 - 45) \cdot 16 = 304.$

So $1 \leq u \leq 3.$

If $u = 3,$ we get $27 + 33 v^2 = 60,$ so $v = \pm 1.$

If $u = 2,$ we get $-52 + 17 v^2 = 60, \; \; 17 v^2 = 112$ so $v$ is not an integer.

If $u = 1,$ we get $-29 +  v^2 = 60, \; \;  v^2 = 89$ so $v$ is not an integer.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ gp
Reading GPRC: /etc/gprc ...Done.

                                       GP/PARI CALCULATOR Version 2.5.0 (released)
                                   i686 running linux (ix86/GMP kernel) 32-bit version
                            compiled: Nov 17 2011, gcc-4.6.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.2-2ubuntu1) 
                                     (readline v6.2 enabled, extended help enabled)

                                         Copyright (C) 2000-2011 The PARI Group

PARI/GP is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and comes WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY WHATSOEVER.

Type ? for help, \q to quit.
Type ?12 for how to get moral (and possibly technical) support.

parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500509
? f = 8 * (x + y) * (x^2 + y^2 ) - 15 * (x^2 + x * y + y^2 + 1) 
%1 = 8*x^3 + (8*y - 15)*x^2 + (8*y^2 - 15*y)*x + (8*y^3 - 15*y^2 - 15)
? 
? g = (16 * (x + y) - 45) * (x + y)^2 + (16 * (x + y) - 15) * (x - y)^2 - 60 
%2 = 32*x^3 + (32*y - 60)*x^2 + (32*y^2 - 60*y)*x + (32*y^3 - 60*y^2 - 60)
? 
? 4 * f - g 
%3 = 0
? 
?
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Comment: After a glance at the equation you wrote, I can see that you have solved a different problem. You can also see this, $16u^3+16uv^2$ has $x^3$ and $y^3$ in its simplest form.

Comment: @user68659, well, no, they are the same. Edited in check by gp-pari. I did multiply by 4, of course.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. Did you use a software to come to this form?

Comment: @user, no, I just wrote $2(x^2 + y^2) = u^2 + v^2$ and $4(x^2 + xy + y^2) = 3 u^2 + v^2.$  So then I needed to multiply through by 4 to clear denominators in the original.  The intermediate step was $$ 16u(u^2 + v^2) = 15 (3 u^2 + v^2 + 4)$$

Comment: Then what's the PARI/GP thing ?

Comment: @user, you expressed doubt.

Answer (score 2):

We deal only with positive $x$ and $y$, so this is quite incomplete.

We can take care of $x+y\le 3$ by inspection. So assume $x+y\ge 4$.  Bring the $x^2+y^2$ stuff to the left side. We get
$$(8x+8y-15)(x^2+y^2) =15(xy+1).$$
The left side is $\ge (17)(2xy)$. So it is bigger than the right.